# IndexOutOfBoundsException when using jsoup get() function

Tags: java, jsoup, indexoutofboundsexception

Basically my function loads a webpage from https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Wikimedia_projects and takes the table so that it prints the name of the language if a certain cell in its row is not empty. Here is the code:

```
public static void getLanguagesFromProject(String project) {
    String html = "https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Wikimedia_projects";
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();
        Elements tableElements = doc.select("table.wikitable.sortable");
        Elements rows = tableElements.select("tr");
        int column = 0;
        switch (project) {
            case "Wikipedia":
                column = 3;
                break;
            case "Wiktionary":
                column = 4;
                break;
            case "Wikibooks":
                column = 5;
                break;
            case "Wikinews":
                column = 6;
                break;
            case "Wikiquote":
                column = 7;
                break;
            case "Wikisource":
                column = 8;
                break;
            case "Wikiversity":
                column = 9;
                break;
            case "Wikivoyage":
                column = 10;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        for (Element row : rows) {
            Elements cols = row.select("td");
            System.out.println(cols.get(column).text());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What happens is that I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException error, specifically in the second statement in the for loop: `System.out.println(cols.get(column).text());`
Any idea what needs to be done?
Edit: the error in more detail:

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out-of-bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:440)
    at com.company.Main.getLanguagesFromProject(Main.java:76)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:11)`

Comment: `Index 3 out-of-bounds for length 0` - no data

Comment: In your switch statement, if no case is triggered, column's value is zero. What happens then? That could be one of your issues.

Comment: No, `column` has been set to three, but there is no data returned from `Elements cols = row.select("td");`

Comment: @tomerpacific I would assume making it zero would AT LEAST print the contents of the first column, but it always gives the same error.

Comment: @AmirulUmar - Have you checked there is data in the first column? Have you checked that the tableElements variable is valid? The error you gave states length is zero, meaning the object you think you have, does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

notice that you have selected all `<tr>`

```
Elements tableElements = doc.select("table.wikitable.sortable");
Elements rows = tableElements.select("tr");
```

including those in the header. Then its first row will be the header that does not have `<td>`, then, in its first iteration, it got an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception when it tries to get the 3rd element `<td>` because it does not exist there.

Just exclude the first `<tr>` that is header

```
// start from 1, exclude 0 which is a header without td's
for (int i = 1; i < rows.size(); i++) {
    Elements cols = rows.get(i).select("td");
    System.out.println(cols.get(column).text());
}
```

Comment: I actually already found my solution before receiving your solution, thanks for the answer however!

Comment: Can you help me with the solution?